# Modelling Population and Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

A population of a species of animal had the following differential equation:

$${dP\over dt} = rP \left(1-{P\over K}\right)$$

$P$ was the population.
$t$ was the time in years.
$K$ was the carrying capacity (which is the ecologically sustainable mass of population the place can hold).

After solving the differential equation (by getting the final equation, rearranging the formula for $P(0)$ and putting it back into this final equation, the formula was:

$$P = {KP_0\over P_0 + (K-P_0)e^{-rt}}$$

The carrying capacity ($K$) is between 50 and 60 kT.

$P_0$ is the initial population which in this situation is between 42 KT and 68 KT.

The rate of increase ($r$) is between $-0.05$ and $0.05.$

1. What parameter is the most important to monitor the population? (I was thinking $r,$ is this right?)
2. What parameters together leads to the most ecologically sustainable population (I was thinking $r$ and initial population but I'm not too sure)
3. Production of food needs to be increased and it is acceptable for the population of the animal species to be reduced by 10% over the next 10 years (1% per year). What $r$ value would be put on the population? (I was not very sure of what to do for this)

Comment: Can we get clarification on the units of KT/kT. Are these supposed to be the same?

Comment: By "parameter", I guess they mean $K, P_0, r$, but not $t$? The problem with questions (1) and (2) is that they are ill-defined (what do you even mean by "monitor the population"? What makes a population "most ecologically sustainable"?) and also opinion-based.

Comment: For (3) they are saying $P(10) =90\%\,P_0$ ($P_0$ being the population at the start of the 10 years), so you need to solve the equation for $r$ in this case. However, the answer is going to depend on the ratio of $P_0$ to $K$, which is not clear from the question (or at least the information you gave here).

Comment: @Mark that was what was written in the question (it must be the same I think [KT])

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ok, understood. This was the most information I got from the question.